# calculating the sum of a formula filed in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I need help in calculating the sum of a formula filed in crystal report. I have a formula filed '@ClosingBalQty' ,I want to calculate the 'sum({ClosingBalQty}).

As its a formula it return an error.Can any one tell me how to just get total of '@ClosingBalQty'

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the error? And seeing the contents of the formula will probably help as well. Edit your question above with those two items.

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy See the error

Comment: You can't sum the already sum value in that way....what is the exact requirement

Comment: To get total of @ClosingBalQty in footer